# Gremlin Python - Script based method not returning all - JanusGraph

Tags: python, gremlin, janusgraph, gremlinpython

I am running JanusGraph 0.3.1 and using gremlin python 3.3.4 and python3.7

> In the test case below, I created 65 vertices. When I use
>   g.V(list_of_ids).valueMap(true).toList(). JanusGraph returns only 64
>   results instead of 65.

As a workaround I am currently passing 64 ids at a time when I have more than 64 ids to pass in g.V(list_of_ids).

> Am I doing something wrong or is there a limitation on the script
>   method when used along with query bindings in gremlin python?

**Schema and code to insert data**

```
// schema creation for graph named newg and traversal source g1

mgmt = newg.openManagement()

//make properties
type = mgmt.makePropertyKey('type').dataType(String.class).cardinality(org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE).make()
id_tx = mgmt.makePropertyKey('id_tx').dataType(String.class).cardinality(org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE).make()

// make vertex label
identity = mgmt.makeVertexLabel('identity').make()
mgmt.addProperties(identity, type, id_tx)

mgmt.commit()

// insert 65 vertices of the label identity

g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','1').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','2').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','3').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','4').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','5').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','6').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','7').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','8').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','9').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','10').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','11').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','12').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','13').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','14').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','15').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','16').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','17').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','18').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','19').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','20').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','21').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','22').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','23').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','24').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','25').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','26').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','27').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','28').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','29').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','30').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','31').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','32').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','33').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','34').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','35').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','36').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','37').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','38').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','39').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','40').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','41').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','42').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','43').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','44').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','45').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','46').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','47').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','48').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','49').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','50').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','51').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','52').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','53').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','54').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','55').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','56').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','57').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','58').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','59').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','60').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','61').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','62').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','63').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','64').property('type','ecn')
g1.addV('identity').property('id_tx','65').property('type','ecn')

gremlin> g1.tx().commit()
==>null
gremlin> g1.V().count()
==>65
```

**Now I try to query from python using GLV and Script methods. GLV method seems to work fine.**

```
(py371local) bash-3.2$ python
Python 3.7.2 (v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 24 2018, 02:44:43) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
# GLV method
>>> from gremlin_python import statics
>>> from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
>>> from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __
>>> from gremlin_python.process.strategies import *
>>> from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection
>>> graph = Graph()
>>> g1 = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', 'g1', username='<<user_id>>', password='<<password>>'))
>>> id_list = g1.V().id().toList()
>>> len(id_list)
65
>>> result = g1.V(id_list).valueMap(True).toList()
>>> result
[{'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 28672, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['31']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 32792, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['57']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 28760, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['52']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 32768, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['35']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12400, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['41']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8344, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['44']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8304, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['19']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 45192, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['49']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 28808, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['32']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4160, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['25']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24688, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['51']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 49288, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['56']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4184, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['8']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8328, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['6']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 16480, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['30']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24600, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['33']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20576, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['34']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12312, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['7']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8216, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['5']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20616, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['27']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 16408, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['10']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4120, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['3']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20504, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['18']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24728, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['17']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 53384, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['59']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4192, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['2']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 32856, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['61']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4096, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['9']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24712, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['29']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 41096, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['46']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 36952, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['64']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 28696, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['48']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 32904, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['36']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 36864, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['37']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24672, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['45']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 49152, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['50']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8256, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['38']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24664, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['28']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 16496, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['43']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 57344, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['65']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 53248, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['58']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 57480, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['62']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8280, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['16']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12288, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['13']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4232, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['1']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12376, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['20']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 16536, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['55']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 16520, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['21']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8288, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['12']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 45056, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['42']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 16472, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['23']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 37000, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['40']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 40960, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['39']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20632, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['60']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20568, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['26']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12424, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['15']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12440, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['53']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20592, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['47']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4248, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['14']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4208, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['4']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8192, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['11']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24576, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['24']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12352, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['63']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20480, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['22']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 28768, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['54']}]
>>> len(result)
65
>>> query = "g1.V(id_list).valueMap(True).toList()"
>>> query_bindings = {"id_list": id_list}

#  Now Try using the script method
>>> from gremlin_python.driver import client
>>> from gremlin_python.driver.serializer import GraphSONSerializersV3d0
>>> db_session = client.Client('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', 'g1', message_serializer=GraphSONSerializersV3d0(), username="<<user_id>>", password="<<password>>")
>>> query = "g1.V(id_list).valueMap(true).toList()"
>>> result = db_session.submit(query, query_bindings).all().result()
>>> result
[{'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 28672, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['31']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 32792, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['57']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 28760, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['52']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 32768, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['35']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12400, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['41']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8344, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['44']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8304, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['19']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 45192, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['49']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 28808, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['32']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4160, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['25']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24688, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['51']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 49288, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['56']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4184, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['8']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8328, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['6']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 16480, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['30']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24600, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['33']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20576, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['34']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12312, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['7']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8216, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['5']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20616, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['27']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 16408, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['10']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4120, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['3']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20504, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['18']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24728, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['17']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 53384, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['59']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4192, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['2']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 32856, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['61']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4096, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['9']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24712, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['29']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 41096, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['46']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 36952, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['64']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 28696, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['48']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 32904, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['36']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 36864, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['37']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24672, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['45']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 49152, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['50']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8256, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['38']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24664, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['28']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 16496, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['43']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 57344, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['65']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 53248, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['58']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 57480, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['62']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8280, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['16']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12288, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['13']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4232, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['1']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12376, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['20']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 16536, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['55']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 16520, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['21']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8288, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['12']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 45056, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['42']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 16472, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['23']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 37000, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['40']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 40960, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['39']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20632, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['60']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20568, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['26']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12424, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['15']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12440, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['53']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20592, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['47']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4248, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['14']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 4208, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['4']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 8192, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['11']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 24576, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['24']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 12352, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['63']}, {'type': ['ecn'], <T.id: 1>: 20480, <T.label: 3>: 'identity', 'id_tx': ['22']}]
>>> len(result)
64
>>> 
# We see only 64 returned instead of 65
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number 64 is interesting because that is the default batch iteration size [defined by the server](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/e900e8d6ae2c0c071420d4f44e647057b067f219/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server.yaml#L51): `resultIterationBatchSize`. I would try to bump that number up to 100, restart the server and see if you get all 65 of your results.

That said, you should not need to do that - if your results exceed the `resultIterationBatchSize` the server should automatically proceed to producing the next batch and streaming that down to your client. I seem to remember a problem with this from a long time ago. I couldn't pinpoint the change in the code, but I remember adding this test:

https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/commit/425bcd032adc9967a6b575da8042df3806671825

which deals with large results that would need to be streamed. Please consider bumping to `gremlinpython` 3.3.5 to see if that resolves the issue. If that doesn't work, try to recreate the problem in Gremlin Server with TinkerGraph and once you have good reproduction steps, submit an issue to [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TINKERPOP/).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Changing resultIterationBatchSize worked out sweet. Now I get all the 65. I bumped the number to 500. As that is the size we plan to page on the UI.